# How to eliminate method side effects?

Tags: coding-style, solid-principles, code-cleanup, side-effects, clean-architecture

I try to be careful about SOLID and clean code principles. I think I fall into side effect error. When I trigger a method it must get data from another service and insert to database:

```
//when I call the method, process starts
public void TriggerProcess()
{
   GetInformationsFromService();
}

public void GetInformationsFromService()
{
   var informations = exampleService.GetInformations();
  
   InsertInformations(informations);
}

public void InsertInformations(informations)
{
   insertThemToDb(informations);
}
```

If someone wants to use only `GetInformationsFromService()` it should not insert data. However, If I call methods like :

```
public void TriggerProcess()
{
   var informations = GetInformationsFromService();
   InsertInformations(informations);
}
```

There will be chain methods which call methods in proper order and there is a middle layer between trigger methods and methods with one responsibility. It seems strange.

```
public void RepresentativeMethod()
{
   method1();
   method2();
   method3();
   //...
}
```

How can I avoid side effect? Which pattern can I use to make a good implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Updating/Inserting data in the database from the data from another service and just viewing of data is two different use cases/process. Don't try to reuse your `GetInformationsFromService()` because it has different purpose. Actually, you must rename it something like `SyncInformation()` and you will have another method called `GetInformation()` just to view data.

Here's what you can do, eliminate the `TriggerProcess()` because `SyncInformation()` is already a process, just call it directly:

This use cases/process should also be included in the **domain layer**:

Synchronize Information Use Case:

```
public void SyncInformation() {
  var informations = exampleService.GetInformations();

  informationRepository.insertInformation(informations);
}
```

Get Information Use Case:

```
public List<Information> GetInformation() {
  return exampleService.getInformation();
}
```

Fetching and saving of data should be in your **data layer**:

ExampleService:

```
public List<Information> getInformation() {
  // logic to fetch from another service, eg: API
}
```

InformationRepository:

```
public void insertInformation(informations)
{
   // insert to database logic
}
```

Here, we are following the **separation of concerns** because we're splitting it into two layers, domain and data. **Domain layer** handles all the application/business logic like for example the steps on how to synchronize of information. **It knows WHEN** it should save data but **it doesn't know HOW**. **Data layer** **knows HOW** to read and save data, but **it doesn't know WHEN** it should happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this principle described below. In OO you can never fully remove side effects (OO is all about managing state), this is the downside of OO. But you can however make code easier to maintain, read and test by following this principle.

## Command Query Separation Principle

> This principle states that every method should either be a *command* that performs an action, or a *query* that returns data to the caller, but not both.

A command method implies a side effect (uses `void`), a query method never has side effects. This makes a clear distinction between the two types of methods, and makes code easier to read, easier to test, and easier to maintain.

### Your code

I think your code:

```java
public void GetInformationsFromService()
{
   var informations = exampleService.GetInformations();
   InsertInformations(informations);
}
```

... can be transformed according to this principle:

```java
public void TriggerProcess() //Command (void!)
{
   InsertInformations(GetInformationsFromService());
}

public /* Informations return type here */ GetInformationsFromService() //Query (no void!, no side effect!)
{
   return exampleService.GetInformations();
}

public void InsertInformations(informations) //Command (void!)
{
  insertThemToDb(informations);
}
```

Or

```java
public void TriggerProcess() //Command
{
   insertThemToDb(GetInformationsFromService());
}

public /* Informations return type here */ GetInformationsFromService() //Query
{
   return exampleService.GetInformations();
}
```

You get the idea...